How to debug not working translation from json file in laravel?
I am currently using php translation files which work properly. For longer strings I wanted to add a json with the corresponding translation. In my case I want to translate strings from german to english, so I added a en.json file in the /lang directory.
I try to echo the translated strings in the blade file as documented like this {{ __($invoice->paymentType->description) }}.
the en.json looks like this (I reduced it to one string)
{
    "Zahlbar binnen 7 Tagen": "Payable within 7 days"
}

The string does not get translated. How can I debug the problem? Or what is the problem? The locale is set to "en", php-file-related translations work on that page.
To clearify: no string gets translated via the en.json file. {{ __('Banane') }}
and
{
    "Banane": "banana"
}

does not work either!
edit: folder structure
lang
├── en.json
├── de
│    ├── invoicing.php
│    └── validation.php
├── en
│    ├── invoicing.php
│    └── validation.php


Can you please share what does it {{ __($invoice->paymentType->description) }} outputs?

it outputs that exact german string. I tried already some simple hardcoded values - no translation.

please share the struct of your lang folder;
try to use {{ __('messages.Banane') }}

i tried to visualize it in my question.
the en.json is located directly in the /lang folder.
your code snipped would lookup in /lang/en/messages.php - this is working in my case!
